# Flash plugin of firefox under Linux

Tags: firefox, flash

I come across a website that warn me to update the flash plugin, I did so, but it still won't play properly.

I use **Firefox 40** and **Adobe Flash 11.2.202.468**, which is the latest for Linux+Firefox accroding to [this](http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/).

I know little thing about Flash, but can somebody please explain to me why its version varing between different browsers?

Why the latest Flash version number for Linux+Firefox is far behind others?

What can I do if the **latest** Flash still need to be updated?

Comment: maybe a way to continue using firefox: http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/2028

Answer (score 0):

Adobe is no longer developing the Flash for Firefox on Linux. You’re still getting security updates, but that’s it — your Flash Player plug-in is already several major versions out-of-date.

Linux users can still use the Pepper-based Flash plug-in included with Google Chrome for Linux. This is the only way to get the latest version of Flash on Linux, although the plug-in can be installed separately for Chromium or Firefox.

[More Info](http://www.howtogeek.com/193876/using-firefox-on-linux-your-flash-player-is-old-and-outdated/)